# How to always display 6 rows on every printed page in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, reportviewer, record

I have 3 rows in one table or 8 rows in one table. I want Report viewer always display 6 rows on every printed page. I found this on the web but it doesn't work with my case

```
if Remainder (RecordNumber, 6) = 0 then true else false
```

This only break after each 6 rows, but doesn't display 6 rows on printed page with case only 3 rows in on a table.(3 rows + 3 blank rows)

Example:

[image]

Comment: So if there are only 3 rows you want to display 6 anyway?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Do you just want blank space with formatting or do you need to have any fields/values in the blank lines?

Comment: I need blank space with formatting :), you can see example image

Comment: I'll have a look at this shortly, there may just be a way to cheat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to cheat using the report footers (if you use groups you'll need to do this using group footers):

First add 5 report footers:

[image: 5 footers]

Then style these as per your detail rows (making sure Footer A, C and E are styled the same as your EVEN rows!):

[image: Row Style]

Set the suppression formulas as below:

```
Footer A : Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) >= 2 or
           Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) = 0

Footer B : Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) >= 3 or
           Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) = 0

Footer C : Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) >= 4 or
           Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) = 0

Footer D : Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) >= 5 or
           Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) = 0

Footer E : Remainder(RecordNumber, 6) = 0
```

This should then work as you need, if you use the Report Footer on the report add another and make it report footer F.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :), I research find some ways: http://forums.asp.net/p/1889197/5349771.aspx?Re+How+to+add+blank+record+after+the+last+detail+on+the+last+page+which+less+than+20+records+ and http://babyt.cnblogs.com/archive/2005/04/15/138214.html

Answer (score 0):

In Section Expert, under Paging,"New Page After n Visible Records", where n is the amount of records. Works only in Detail Section.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: This break after each 6 rows and always display 6 rows on every page?

Comment: I want to always display 6 rows on every page. Example: I have 3 rows --> display:( 3 rows + 3 rows is blank)

Answer (score 0):

Where we have to give the suppression formula. did this method is working correctly

Comment: I can see English is not your native language, so no offense, but this answer is difficult to understand.  Can you please explain more and perhaps we can help you express what you are trying to say?